# Under what conditions, lrpid of message queue will remain 0 in output of ipcs -qa?

Tags: c, unix, ipcs

So, I have taken output of ipcs -qa, and I am getting output something like this :

```
T  ID   KEY     MODE        OWNER GROUP CREATOR CGROUP CBYTES QNUM QBYTES LSPID LRPID  STIME    RTIME   CTIME
q 1111  0X1111 --rw-rw----  oname gname oname   gname  1262   1    65000  222222  0   07:11:01 no-entry 07:06:00
q 2222  0x2222 --rw-rw----  oname gname oname   gname  0      0    65000   0      0   no-entry no-entry 08:40:54
```

The data is only indicative, but observations in this are there is 1 message is present in the queue, which is probably created by the process ID under LSPID, but the process ID under LRPID is 0. Since no process ID has received message from queue so RTIME value is no-entry.

I want to understand under what conditions a queue is created  but no process receives the message.

Additionally under second output of the command, the number of QNUM is also 0, indicating there no message in the queue, but a queue is created. In what condition would a queue be created but no process is able to send message in the queue. The queue creation, and access is both happening with same user which is the owner of the queue, so permission issue might not be there.

I understand this output is specific to my application itself, but I am hoping to understand if there could be any generic criteria, like timeout, or something, that could result in situation like this.

I am using C language ipc library.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So it seems this issue mostly came because of timeout issues. The code was not gracefully handling the timeout and load on servers.